How to make an image bigger than the card but still inside the card with Bootstrap?
How to make a card with a design like the image below using Bootstrap 5.3.3 and HTML on the website


an element will by default always have the height to fit-content the child elements. The only way you can prevent this is by moving the child element out of flow!

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You can set the height of the div with position: relative, and make the image height more than the div and position: absolute; then you can have the image bigger than the div (card)
Example:


div { width: 250px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid #333; border-radius:10px; position: relative; padding-left: 120px;}
div img { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 120px; left: -2px; top: -20px; border-radius: 10px;}
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <h4>Subtitle</h4>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/536/354" alt="image">
</div> 



